# Call a function using $('.class').each(functionName);

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a codepen here - 
http://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/EjMbQp

```
function homepanelHeights() {
    $('.img_panel').each(function() {
        if (currentWidth < 700) {
            var panelcopyHeight = $(this).find('.panel_copy_inner').outerHeight();
            console.log(panelcopyHeight);
            $(this).css('height', panelcopyHeight);
        } else {
            // remove inline style
            $(this).css("height", "");
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.img_panel').each(homepanelHeights);
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.img_panel').each(homepanelHeights);
});
```

I want to apply a function to each element with .img_panel. 
Do you know why the each function call is not working?
I assume its because of the arguments I'm passing, but can not work it out.

it works if I simply repeat the function in the doc.ready and window.resize, but that is a bit dirty..

Hope you can help!

Comment: Why another for each in the `fucntion homepanelHeights`?

Comment: You don't need `$('.img_panel').each(homepanelHeights);`. You're already iterating over the selector in the function. Just use `homepanelHeights()` within the `document.ready` function.

Comment: Where is `currentWidth` defined?

Comment: I'd use `$(window).on('load resize', homepanelHeights);` and not ready pseudo handler which can give wrong result for elements size depending content

Comment: sry for missing variable and repeated.each, pen updated here - http://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/EjMbQp
(its not letting me edit my main post :/)

Answer (score 3):

1. You just need to call `homepanelHeights();` Because when you using `$('.img_panel').each(...)` in `homepanelHeights`, you're already iterating through it, `$('.img_panel').each(homepanelHeights);`, combine with the logic inside the function, can be considered as:

```
// This is the outer    
$('.img_panel').each(function() {
    // This is inside your homepanelHeights
    $('.img_panel').each(function() {
       // Do something.
    });
});
```

So you can see that that the logic `n*n times`.

2. `currentWidth` is `undefined` in your codepen. Added a fake to show.

```js
function homepanelHeights(){
$('.img_panel').each(function (){
    // VVVV Make the `currentWidth` get value here, it needs the current width
    // when window content is fully loaded, or resized.
    var currentWidth = $(window).width();
 if (currentWidth < 700){ 
  var panelcopyHeight = $(this).find('.panel_copy_inner').outerHeight();
  console.log(panelcopyHeight);
  $(this).css('height', panelcopyHeight);
   } else {
   // remove inline style
  $(this).css("height", "");
 }
});
}

// As A. Wolff  said :
// $(window).on('load resize', homepanelHeights);  Can simplify the code.
$(document).ready(function() {
  homepanelHeights();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  homepanelHeights();
});
```

```css
.img_panel {background:salmon; width:200px; height:300px; margin-bottom:10px; display:table;
 .panel_copy_inner {height:100%;     display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align: center;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img_panel">
 <div class="panel_copy_inner">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="img_panel">
 <div class="panel_copy_inner">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="img_panel">
 <div class="panel_copy_inner">Test</div>
</div>
```

If you want to use the function `homepanelHeights`   as `$('.img_panel').each(homepanelHeights);`

You can rewrite the logic to:

```
var currentWidth;
// You need to either define a `currentWidth` here by something.
function homepanelHeights(){
    if (currentWidth < 700){    
        var panelcopyHeight = $(this).find('.panel_copy_inner').outerHeight();
        console.log(panelcopyHeight);
        $(this).css('height', panelcopyHeight);
            } else {
            // remove inline style
        $(this).css("height", "");
    }
}

// As A. Wolff  said :

$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    // Update the width here. So you don't need to get currentWidth 
    // each time you operate on an element.
    currentWidth = $(window).width();
    $('.img_panel').each(homepanelHeights);
});
```

Demo is on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0rmnp0u/).

Comment: thanks so much for the help mate!
I've updated the pen here - http://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/EjMbQp
but still doesn't seem to be working...

I'd also be interested in how to get this working using a sytax like - 
$('.img_panel').each(homepanelHeights);

Comment: @Ash You put the `currentWidth`  at wrong place, I've update the answer according to your pen's change, take a look.

Comment: @Ash Added how you can use `$('.img_panel').each(homepanelHeights);` below the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
     function homepanelHeights(){
            //This will iterate through all element having img_panel class
            $('.img_panel').each(function(){
                 //get current div's height
                 var currentWidth = //assign some value here, it is undefined in your current code;
                 // your logic implemetation
                 if (currentWidth < 700)
                 {  
                    var panelcopyHeight = $(this).find('.panel_copy_inner').outerHeight();
                    console.log(panelcopyHeight);
                    $(this).css('height', panelcopyHeight);
                 } 
                else {
                  $(this).css("height", "");
                }
            })
        }
        // on window load && resize 
        $(window).on('load resize',function() {
          homepanelHeights(); 
        });
//Or instead of window on load you can also use document's ready event
        $(document).ready(function() {
          homepanelHeights(); 
        });


document.ready runs when the DOM is ready, e.g. all elements are there to be found/used, but not necessarily all the content. 

window.onload fires later (or at the same time in the worst/failing cases) when images and such are loaded. So, if you're using image dimensions for example, you often want to use this instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have modified the code to achieve the functionality for **each** element.
Please see the code below.

```
homepanelHeights=function(key, val) {

var currentWidth = $(window).width();
console.log(currentWidth);
        if (currentWidth < 700) {
            var panelcopyHeight = $(this).find('.panel_copy_inner').outerHeight();
            //console.log(panelcopyHeight);
            $(this).css('height', panelcopyHeight);
        } else {
            // remove inline style
            $(this).css("height", "");
        }

}

/**/
$(document).ready(function() {    

$('.img_panel').each(homepanelHeights); 

});

$(window).resize(function() {
   $('.img_panel').each(homepanelHeights);
});
```